# Alertdialog with integrated buttons in the message

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to do something like Terms of Service in an `AlertDialog` (it must pop up) where the user has to scroll to the bottom to see the "accept" or possible an accompanying decline button. Is there a way to include buttons in the `AlertDialog`s MESSAGE that the user must scroll through?

Similarly another implementation would just be to have the button unpressable until the user scrolls to the bottom, how would I do that?

Insight appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could always create a custom `Dialog` and show that. There's a guide on how to do that on the Android developer site right here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

An alternative would be to create a regular class with its own layout and then set the theme to the dialog theme. This will look like a dialog when opening, and allows for pretty much the same functionality as any other `Activity`.

Comment: I think you are right! So I just make a new layout and inflate that, very cool

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you can do is, compare the bottom position of the last item in the dialog, which would be the textview, to the bottom of the scrollview in the onScrollChanged listener. This way, when the user has reached the bottom, you can call

```
 AlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dBuilder.setMessage(msg)
.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    })
.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    /// YOUR OK PART
});
AlertDialog alert = dBuilder.create();
alert.show();
```

Obviously msg contains your... message :)

Comment: right, but `msg` is a string message, I want the message to contain buttons and a scrollview

Comment: If your message is long, scroll will be applied automatically. Buttons will be added too - 'Accept' and 'Cancel'. So it should give you exactly what you have asked for.

Comment: I want a user to have to scroll to the bottom of the `msg` to see any buttons. Your method here just gives me an alert of a fixed size where the buttons are always seen at the bottom of the message regardless of  if the user has scrolled the msg or not. I just confirmed this with a really long `msg`. The solution is a custom alertdialog